# В папке DCIM создается не нужная копия фото, как сделать чтобы не создавалась?

Tags: java, android

Вызываю активность для получения фото следующим кодом:

```
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            File fileTemp;
            File pathTemp;
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                pathTemp = new File(DB.pathData, TEMP_DIR);
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error_foto, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                return;
            }

            if (!pathTemp.exists()) pathTemp.mkdirs(); // если нет папки TEMP создаст ее

            fileTemp = new File(pathTemp.getAbsolutePath(), "IMG_" +DB
                    .dateToString(Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), DB.DATE_FORMAT_FILE)
                    + ".jpg");


            mOutputFileTempUri = Uri.fromFile(fileTemp);

            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mOutputFileTempUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

получаю результат:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (( requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE)&&(resultCode == RESULT_OK)){

        if ( data != null) {
            if (data.hasExtra("data")) {
                Bitmap thingBitmap = data.getParcelableExtra("data");
                // TODO Какие-то действия с миниатюрой
                mFotoIV.setImageBitmap(thingBitmap);
            }
        } else {
            // TODO Какие-то действия с полноценным изображением,
            // сохраненным по адресу mOutputFileTempUriUri
            mFotoIV.setImageURI(mOutputFileTempUri);
            mSignature.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

        mFotoIV.setBackgroundColor(0); // обнуляем фон

    } else mOutputFileTempUri = null;


} // onActivityResult
```

кроме как в mOutputFileTempUri, появляется фотография в DCIM, как сделать так, чтобы она там не появлялась?

Comment: это зависит от приложения *камера*. Оно само решает, созхдавать его там, или нет. Скорее всего, приказать ему вы не сможете

Comment: Значит чтобы достичь моей цели, нужна создать свое активити с обработкой камеры?

Comment: или, как минимум, чтобы подтвердить или опровергнуть мою теорию, попробовать на другом телефоне, желательно вовсе другого производителя

Comment: А можно как-нибудь найти это фото в папке DCIM и удалить?

Comment: можете попробовать найти последний созданный файл, посмотреть у него дату, и, если она совпадает с моментом снимка - удалить его

Comment: Такой же вопрос есть на SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940270/android-duplicate-photo-storage-in-dcim-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использую следующий метод. В него передается сохраненный файл с камеры, а дальше осуществляется поиск по сделанным недавно фото. Если был найден такой же файл, сделаный с разницей менее 10 секунд, относительно полученного файла, то дубликат удаляется и рассылается `Intent` с оповещением об удалении этого файла.

```
    private static void checkAndDeleteDuplicatePhotos(@Nullable File photoFile, @NotNull Context ctx){
    if (photoFile == null) {
        Log.w("photo file is null, returning...");
        return;
    }
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_MODIFIED
    };
    Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver()
                       .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                              projection,
                              null,
                              null,
                              MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_MODIFIED + " DESC");
    if (cursor == null) {
        Log.w("cursor is null, returning");
        return;
    }
    if (! cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.w("cursor is empty, returning");
        cursor.close();
        return;
    }
    do {
        long date = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_MODIFIED)) * 1000;
        long diff = Math.abs(date - photoFile.lastModified());
        Log.i("\nphotoFile.lastModified() = " + photoFile.lastModified() + "\ndate = " + date + "\nDiff = " + diff);
        if (diff > 10000) break;
        File file = new File(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)));

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        options.inSampleSize = 16; //to avoid OOM Error

        Bitmap bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), options);
        Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getPath(), options);

        boolean same = bm1.sameAs(bm2);
        Log.i("Comparing bitmaps... " + same);
        if (same) {
            Log.i("Deleting duplicate... " + file.delete());
            try {
                Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
                ctx.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w(e);
            }
            break;
        }
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
}
```